# Getting @mention from feedcomment.?

Tags: apex, visualforce, chatter-feed

Is there a way we can get @mention user from feedcomment.I got the @user from FeedItem.but how to get it from feedcomment.

urgent help is required.

```
List<ConnectApi.MessageSegment> messageSegments = feedItem.CommentBody.messageSegments;
            for (ConnectApi.MessageSegment messageSegment : messageSegments) {
                if (messageSegment instanceof ConnectApi.MentionSegment) {
                    ConnectApi.MentionSegment mentionSegment = (ConnectApi.MentionSegment) messageSegment;
                    System.debug('Mentioned user name: ' + mentionSegment.name);
                    System.debug('Mentioned user id: ' + mentionSegment.record.Id);
```

**Updated**

```
for(FeedComment feedRec:Trigger.new)  
        {
            String communityId = null;
            String feedItemId = feedRec.FeedItemId;

            ConnectApi.FeedElement feedItem = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElement(communityId, feedItemId);
            System.debug('========ffff====='+feedItem.capabilities.comments.page.items);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a feed item "f" of type [ConnectApi.FeedItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_Feed_Item.htm), you can access its comments (which is a List<[ConnectApi.Comment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_comment.htm)>) with:

```
f.capabilities.comments.page.items
```

And then you can get the message segments for each comment "c" in the list with:

```
c.body.messageSegments
```

Note that this applies to API version 32.0 and higher.

If you're using v31.0, change "page.items" to "page.comments".

If you're using v30.0 or earlier, the list of comments will be in f.comments.comments.

Comment: I have updated my code..Can you please tell how to get exactly user id which the user has used in @mention in the comment..So i want the "mention" user from the latest comment on the feed...How to drill down.??

Comment: In your FeedComment trigger, you don't need to call ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElement(). Instead, you can call ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getComment(communityId, feedRec.id). That will return a ConnectApi.Comment, and you can get the message segments from the body.messageSegments property of the comment. Once you have the message segments, you can use the same code that you wrote for getting the @mention ID from the feed item.